# Trying to create a simple python web crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have decided to learn python 2.7 coding for data analysis and have been watching many tutorials on youtube to get a good understanding of the basics.

I am at the stage where I want to create simple web-crawlers for educational purposes only to learn different techniques and just get used to some of the coding.

I am following a tutorial for a web-crawler but I am not sure of a few things. This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.aflcio.org/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts'
r = requests.get(url)
plain_text = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
statements = soup.findAll('div','ec_statements')

for link in statements:
    print (link.contents)
```

I can't seem to get the href links to separate and have the text and date information displayed.

I want it to look like this:

1. Name of Article
2. Link to Article
3. Date of Article

Could someone help with some information on why those steps were taken please?

Much appreciated!

Comment: You need to call "find" on each link to extract the piece of information you are interested in. Keep looking at the Beautiful Soup docs

Comment: Thanks jeff, I'll keep reading the beautiful soup docs as well to see if I can find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little code to help you.In bs4,all node are connection,you all read get a "link" node(actually is a div),you want to get his child like tag a,so `link.a` is ok.

then, a node have two part values, one is attribute,access by `a['href']`, and content access by `a.text`.

```
for link in statements:
    print(link.a['href'])
```

ps:
this is the link variable:

```
<div id="legalert_title"><a href="/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts/Letter-to-Representatives-opposing-the-Fairness-in-Class-Action-Litigation-and-Furthering-Asbestos-Claim-Transparency-Act">Letter to Representatives opposing the "Fairness in Class Action Litigation and Furthering Asbestos Claim Transparency Act"</a></div>
```

this is link.a:

```
<a href="/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts/Letter-to-Representatives-opposing-the-Fairness-in-Class-Action-Litigation-and-Furthering-Asbestos-Claim-Transparency-Act">Letter to Representatives opposing the "Fairness in Class Action Litigation and Furthering Asbestos Claim Transparency Act"</a>
```

this is link.a['href']:

```
/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts/Letter-to-Representatives-opposing-the-Fairness-in-Class-Action-Litigation-and-Furthering-Asbestos-Claim-Transparency-Act
```

this is .text:

```
Letter to Representatives opposing the "Fairness in Class Action Litigation and Furthering Asbestos Claim Transparency Act"
```

all html is in this way, maybe you need learn a little html.

Comment: Thanks Pete, just for clarification, why is 'href' in square brackets '[ ]' and not in normal brackets '( )'?

Comment: e,it is about `data structure`, way to connect and explain data.

Comment: e,it is about `data structure`, way to connect and explain data.
link.a("href") means a is a `class method`,href is the param.you can design something like these as you want,but it is not a good way, because method is a verbose,i do not know how to tell you these, some example:

    people.walk() #walk is a action.
    #but some thing is attribute
    people.parens # this is not a action, it is something people have.
                            # and parens is a `dict` ({"mom": name, "father": name})
    which you can do this
    people.parens['mom'] # return mom's name